# Какой наиболее производительный метод очистки div от текста?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такого типа div:

```
<div class="div">
  <span class="div__title"></span>
</div>
```

Я обрабатываю текст и используя `insertAdjacentText()` вставляю текст, но мне необходимо очищать данный `span` после определенной операции. Обычный `innerHTML=""` слишком медлителен и мне нужен более производительный вариант.

Как можно удалить текст внутри тега максимально быстро?

Comment: .3мб, очистка происходит 15 мс, но таких блоков 30 штук и начинает лагать

Comment: Если браузер замерзает, можно попробовать запустить чистку в цикл через `setTimeout(function loop(){ /* удаление, условие - запускающее след итерацию */ setTimeout(loop); })`, а не обычный for... и дать N миллисекунд времени на отдых)

Comment: Могу предположить, что лагает не сама очистка, а отрисовка нового элемента. Можно попробовать запустить очистку текста в requestAnimationFrame. Но это не точно. Сама очистка происходит достаточно быстро, т.к. innerHTML это по сути сброс указателя памяти на другую область (эта операция O(1)). Скорее всего у вас проблема в отрисовке.

Comment: А в каком браузере тестили? И нет ли ссылки на сайт? Что-то не получается воспроизвести проблему... 30 блоков, в каждом 3 МБ текста (рандомного). Загружалось чуть дольше, чем "писец как долго". А любой из блоков в хроме удаляется за 4-5 мс.